# Download and Upload ETL Job from Java for AWS Glue ETL

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

can someone please tell me how I can download or upload a job using the Java API?

I tried searching for an SDK or REST API to download jobs but couldn't find any.

There is an API to delete the job, but there is no API to download or upload the job from the Java SDK.

I tried the following code, but it is not providing the information that I obtain in the downloaded JSON.

```
GetJobRequest getJobRequest = new GetJobRequest().withJobName(jobName); 
GetJobResult  getJobResult  = glueClient.getJob(getJobRequest); 
String        jobJson       = getJobResult.getJob().toString();
```

Comment: GetJobRequest getJobRequest = new GetJobRequest().withJobName(jobName);
        GetJobResult getJobResult = glueClient.getJob(getJobRequest);
        String jobJson = getJobResult.getJob().toString();

Comment: Look at AWS Code Library here for AWS SDK/API code examples-- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html